# apache2 Service is not able to start

Tags: server, apache2, apache2.4, nextcloud

Apache2 is not able to restart because the control process exited with error code.

[image: screenshot]

---

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
serveradmin Rabie@Laassal
docummenRoot "/var/www/html/nextcloud/"
serverName 192.168.159.132
serverAlias ubuntu
<Directory "/var/www/html/nextcloud/">
option +followsymLinks    <= 7th line
Allowoverride All
...
</directory>
```

.
.
.

Comment: You need to learn how to read server logs.  If you read the actual output, you'd see that before it says it failed to start, that you have a syntax error in your configuration.  That is why it fails to start.  Without the details of your configuration, we can't give you any guidance to fix the problem.

Comment: As the error message says there's an error in line 7 of the file `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/nextcloud.conf`. Please add that line to your question.

Comment: the file is  bellow sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some testing in LXD containers, and now that you provided as close to a useful config as is possible, I discovered that "Option" is not valid, but "Options" is valid.

This is an example of this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <Directory />
        Options +FollowSymLinks
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

So, `Options`, not `Option`.

---

Original answer, without details and testing available, is still available [here](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1002437/1) for historical purposes.

Comment: yes U're right sir, now the service is able to restart.